# FIrst dropdown item to be fixed in autoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I created an app that has an `autoCompleteTextView` in order to allow the user to perform search queries.

Once they start typing, a dropdown appears and offers the results.

[image]

Now, I would like to make the first item to be fixed and unscrollable which will say something like: `can't find? add manually`.

How can I make the first item in the suggested dropdown list to be fixed and appear always?

My code for the adapter is:

```
public class AutoCompleteImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> fullList;
    private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter;
    private Boolean noResults;
    private TextView tv_name;
    private ImageView im_cover;
    private List<String> url, id;

    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;

    public AutoCompleteImageAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, List<String> url, List<String> id, Boolean noResult) {

        super( context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects );
        fullList = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>( fullList );
        noResults = noResult;
        this.url = url;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (fullList.size() > 40) {
            return 40;
        } else {
            return fullList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return fullList.get( position );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        View row = convertView;

        String id = this.id.get( position );
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() );

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_auto_add, parent, false );
        }

        tv_name = (TextView) row.findViewById( R.id.item_drop );
        tv_name.setText( fullList.get( position ) );

        im_cover = row.findViewById( R.id.iv_itemCover );
        String Url = url.get( position );
        if (id.length() > AppConstants.UPLOADED_item_LENGTH) {
            storageRef.child( "/itemCovers/" + Url + "/" + Url + ".jpg" ).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Picasso.with( parent.getContext() ).load( uri ).resize( 110, 160 ).into( im_cover );
                }
            } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Log.d( "ERROR", exception + "" );
                }
            } );
        } else {
            Picasso.with( parent.getContext() ).load( Uri.parse( Url ) ).error( R.drawable.ic_nocover ).resize( 110, 160 ).into( im_cover );
        }


        return row;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        private Object lock;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>( fullList );
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>( mOriginalValues );
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<String> values = mOriginalValues;
                int count = values.size();

                ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>( count );

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String item = values.get( i );
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains( prefixString )) {
                        newValues.add( item );
                    }

                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.values != null) {
                fullList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            } else {
                fullList = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (fullList != null) {
            fullList.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's better to follow this design pattern https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVQOR.png. Here you have full flexibility to change the UI.

Comment: Is there a name to this kind of design so I could find more data about it?

Comment: It's easy to implement. Just you have to add two widgets to your screen. 1
1)Edit text with text watcher.
2)Recycle view to show searched result in list.
 In recycle view use this https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview library to achieve your use case.

Comment: I will be honest, I tried to achieve it by poping a textview that will be below the recyclerview. I had problems that they didnt pop up same time even tho that it was placed in the watcher as well. Do you mean to place header to create that spacing like in the picture you posted?

Comment: Use the sticky header libray. It will help you to add your first item at top of the list as well as when user scroll the list then also first item will be showned at the top. https://i.imgur.com/I0ztoPw.gif

Comment: just for a clarification. you want a text bar floating always in the top even if the user scrolls or type for search?

Comment: @vishal N yes, but im struggling using ShreeshaDas solution wheb it comes to combining autocomplete filtered results inside a recyclerview so I was wondering why cant ai just edit that autocomplete functionality

Comment: I have tried a simple xml code in my project and it works like. If user types inthe text view  the message is shown at the last for all the searches.

Answer (score 0):

add it as the first item to your List objects before you pass it to the adapter and then populate the list with data you wanna show as search result so that element 0 is always "can't find? add manually". This way it is always there and the other items change.

and then in the item click listener you can check for the item text and act accordingly if it matches "can't find? add manually".

Comment: But it will still scroll as all the other items once it is added. Correct me if im wrong. I want it to be a sticky item or header, not sure how to call it.

Comment: I see. I understand this is not the answer to your question but isn't it more logical to have this as the last item on the filtered search result so that when the user scrolls down to the last item and they realize they haven't found the intended result, they see (as the last option) that they have the option of adding the item themselves?

Comment: My goal is that the user will "remember" this option no matter how far he scrolled. If I show many results which my algorithm thinks that is correct but they got tired from scrolling 100 results, they would be abls to click on it right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below solves your requirement to some level. Do try and comment.

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/project"
        android:id="@+id/edit_project"
        android:completionThreshold="0"
        android:completionHint="@string/message"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

This code gives a hint at the bottom of the list to the user.

Comment: It shows it at the buttom and I see it doesnt have a click option + it disappears when no results are found and I want it to be sticky.